# getting an ultragridcolumn's actual width

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

How can I accurately get an expanded UltraGridColumn's width within and UltraGrid?

I have the following Windows Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IEnumerable<string> test = new List<string>{DateTime.Now.ToString()};
        this.ultraGrid2.DataSource = test;
        this.ultraGrid2.DisplayLayout.AutoFitStyle = AutoFitStyle.ExtendLastColumn;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The column width is " + this.ultraGrid2.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Width);
    }
}
```

[image: what the form looks like]

Regardless of how I manipulate or resize the form. The `width` still gives the same default value. Only if I resize the column will it change. In this case, I would think that the width would be close to the x size of the form itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the `AutoFitStyle` to `ExtendLastColumn` the `Width` property on the last column doesn't reflect the actual width of the column. If you you set the `AutoFitStyle` to `None` you could set and read the column Width.

However, at least just for reading, there is a workaround:
In your example above, with only one column, you can get the CellSizeResolved property of the column

```
UltraGridColumn column = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0];
Debug.WriteLine("Column width is " + column.CellSizeResolved.Width);
```

Comment: For me `CellSizeResolved` does not work.
Instead, I have to use `((Infragistics.Win.Layout.ILayoutItem)column).PreferredSize.Width`